# http Post says its working but it isn't posting on localhost

Tags: swift, http, go, post

I've been trying to do an HTTP post to my localhost using swift for a mobile app, it prints `Result -> Optional(["user": larry])` which should mean it works but it isn't posting anything on my localhost. My code is:

```
func ReqUsers() -> Void {

        let json = ["user":"larry"]

        do {

            let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)

            let url = NSURL(string: "http://192.168.1.318:8080")! /*localhost*/
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url as URL)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"

            request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpBody = jsonData

            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data, response, error in
                if error != nil{
                    print("Error -> \(String(describing: error))")
                    return
                }
                do {
                    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: /*data!*/ request.httpBody!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    print("Result -> \(String(describing: result))")
                    
                } catch {
                    print(response!)
                    print("Error -> \(error)")
                    print("that")
                }
            }

            task.resume()
        } catch {
            print(error)
            print("this")
        }
        print("called")
    }
```

thanks for your time

for more info on the backend it's being written with goLang and here is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    //"os"
    //"io/ioutil"
    //"log"
    "net/http"
)


func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
   
}

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello")
}
```

Comment: You should be passing `data` to `JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:)`. Not `request.httpBody`

Comment: @RobertCrabtree I've tried that initially but doing so gives out an Error:  Error -> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}`

Comment: You need to find out what's being stored in `data`. `print(String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "INVALID")`

Comment: @RobertCrabtree it gives the data printed by the server "Hello"

Comment: @CamilleBasbous so, what's the problem if server response is being printed?

Comment: @gcharita the server is exiting rather than retrieving the data, the front end is not posting it on the localhost

Comment: are you testing this on a physical device or in a simulator? why not use actual `http://localhost:8080` vs your network address? could be a networking issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see logs in your server, may be caused by `URLSession`'s cache policy.

Try to set the `cachePolicy` property of your `URLRequest` to [.reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/reloadignoringlocalandremotecachedata) or [.reloadIgnoringCacheData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/1417522-reloadignoringcachedata) and see if that works:

```
let url = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.318:8080")! /*localhost*/
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = jsonData
request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
// or
request.cachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringCacheData
```

Comment: thanks for taking your time on this, but its not. working my server gives back: missing protocol scheme
exit status 1

Comment: That's a server side issue: check [this link](https://nanxiao.me/en/fix-unsupported-protocol-scheme-issue-in-golang/)

Comment: the server is fine it can get and post what you see is a listen to port with a / for all path within the host, for GET the full URL is written but it does not recognize any that sent by the mobile app

Comment: if you want. we can vid chat so that i can show you what going on

Comment: @CamilleBasbous do you have any working example of your API call, in let's say Postman maybe?